Visual Basic 6.0 crashing when adding Windows Common Controls (MSCOMCT2.OCX)
I am trying to add the above OCX as a reference to my VB6 project but whenever I add it, my system just hangs and I have to forecefully close the program
I have registered the ocx beforehand using regsvr32
I have Office365 running on Windows11

Perhaps re-install the component and/or validate it..?   Or, if possible, try a different machine w/ the same operation.  Since it worked for many people over the years, it is likely something machine-specific.

What do you mean "crash"?  The "system" hangs - do you mean just VB6 itself? The entire Windows operating system? There is not much detail.

R_click vb project file and open with notepad.
update line
Object={86CF1D34-0C5F-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}#1.0#0; MSCOMCT2.OCX
to
Object={86CF1D34-0C5F-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}#2.0#0; MSCOMCT2.OCX
save
and enjoy.
